# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Tags: php, query-string

Only 1 parameter is needed in fetch assoc but I'm checking to see if the username is found and it gives me an error because it only expects one parameter.

```
function user_exists($username) {
   $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","c3392262");
   $username = sanitize($username);
   $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM 'users' WHERE `username` =           '$username'");
 return (mysqli_fetch_assoc($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: What is your question, and what language is this?

Comment: php return (mysqli_fetch_assoc($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; keeps giving me an error because it only expects one paratmeter

Comment: I don't understand... then why are you giving it two parameters?

Comment: It's telling you you can't have two parameters in mysqli_fetch_assoc so try removing the second one.

Comment: to see if the username is found in the database

Comment: That's not how you use the function... and you are aware that's not how you use the function, yet you still use the function that way.

Comment: what other function would u recommend that i use

Comment: The problem is you are using mysqli functions as if they are mysql functions - I will post an answer in a minute to show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: You would still use that function, with just 1 parameter... look at the resulting array value and if it's 1 there's a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, mysqli_fetch_assoc() only expects 1 parameter, but you're passing 2.
Plus the function returns either an associative array or NULL, so you should rather test its return value against NULL:

```
return (mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)!=NULL)?true:false
```

On a side note, you don't really need to use brackets, since != has a higher priority than ?: already

```
return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)!=NULL?true:false
```

Plus, as pointed out by @rar, you don't really need to use the ternary operator either, since the comparison between mysqli_fetch_assoc() and NULL "returns" a boolean value already

```
return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)!=NULL
```

Comment: Adding to this, is the ternary statement really needed here? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just do: `return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)!=NULL` ?